# Can both fields in a $p$-modular system be algebraically closed at the same time?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $(K,\mathcal{O},k)$ be a $p$-modular system. That is, $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, $\mathcal{O}$ is a complete discrete valuation ring such that $\mathcal{O}/J(\mathcal{O})\cong k$, and $K:=\text{Frac}(\mathcal{O})$, the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}$, is a field of characteristic zero.

Let both $k$ and $K$ be splitting fields for $G$ and its subgroups. That is, all simple $LH$-modules are absolutely simple, for all subgroups $H$ of $G$ and $L\in\{k,K\}$.

Let $k$ be algebraically closed.

Can $K$ be algebraically closed in this case?

Comment: Might be helpful to define $p$-modular system.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Let $\nu$ be the discrete valuation on $K$ and let $u\in K$ be an element with $\nu(u)$ minimal subject to $\nu(u)>0$.

If $K$ were algebraically closed then $u$ would have a square root $\sqrt{u}\in K$, with $\nu(\sqrt{u})=\frac{1}{2}\nu(u)$, contradicting the minimality of $\nu(u)$.

Comment: I've often wondered whether it would make sense to allow rank one indiscrete valuations in order to allow $K$ to be algebraically closed. But I don't really know what could be gained by doing this.